# jQuery script to get only checkboxes with a given prefix

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I'm using the jQuery script listed bellow in order to select a few checkbox inputs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    var column = "table #" + $(this).attr("name");                            
    $(column).hide();
  });

  $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var column = "table #" + $(this).attr("name");                            
    $(column).toggle();
  });
});
```

How can I modify the script in order to get only the those checkboxes where there name starts with "col_"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can choose attribute with `^=` to indicate prefix `$=` suffix etc

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
$('input:checkbox[name^=col_]')
```